# How to change position of close search button at the toolbar in android and animate when expand?

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar

I have search field at the toolbar,but when I tap something the **Close button** appears not on the right side. Also when I tap to **Search button** there are no any animation..

It has some margin.How I can set the position of this **Close button** exactly on the right side of the toolbar? And how add animations when this field is expanding?
[image]

This is code

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home_activity, menu);

        final MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchView_ = (SearchView) myActionMenuItem.getActionView();
        searchView_.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // TODO Make search here
                myActionMenuItem.collapseActionView();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

This is layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="@string/search_label"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Pixel2 screen.
I belive that it's not a close button position problem. It's a SearchView width not enough to fill the toolBar. I spent alot of time trying to change paddings and position of the close button, but it didn't works for me. So I tried to change SearchView size and it works:

```
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```